# Call Spring init method based on condiction

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

I am working 2 different processes.

I am passing process name in JVM argument. Using that argument either of the processes should call.

my app context XML.

```
<bean id="propertyPlaceHolderConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath*:properties/${processJVMArg}.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
<bean id="splitService" class="com.split.service.SplitService" init-method="process1"><!-- "based on processJVMArg JVM argument should call process1 or process2. " -->
```

Is there is a way to configure more than one init method, init method should call based on conduction?

Thanks,

Rama

Comment: Based on *conduction*? What does that mean in programming?

Comment: You should look into using the Profile feature of Spring. See Spring Framework Reference Documentation - [Chapter 7.13 Environment abstraction](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-environment)

Answer (score 2):

Spring has profiles. Based on set of conditions you can start app with exact profile. Bean `beanCreatingBasedOnProfile` will be created only in `dev` profile.

```
@Bean
@Profile("dev")
public YourClass beanCreatingBasedOnProfile() {
    return new YourClass();
}
```

Also spring has  [Conditional Beans](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Conditional.html) .
You can construct bean based on property value or anything else. For example:

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "spring.prop", name = "dynamic", matchIfMissing = true)
public YourClass condBean() {
    return new YourClass();
}
```